# how to redirect output to console window?

Tags: c, file-handling

I write simple console functions and use freopen to redirect printf statements to a file. Can the output to the file be "turned off" and the printf outputs redirected back to the console window later in the code?

Comment: why not use fprintf for the file writes and not go through the bother of redirecting?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`fprintf` lets you to print to a specific file stream. For example,

```
fprintf(stdout, "message");
```

print `message` in the standard output (the console), so... as you see, `printf` is just an specialization of `fprintf`.

I hope this help.